# Order By based on a condition

Tags: mysql

My output looks like this:

```
Dept_Name                      Count(Emp_ID)                           
Commerce                            20                
Science                             15                           
Arts                                15 
Engg.                               10
```

I want to order it on the count(Emp_id) in descending order and if the number is same(Eg. Science & Arts), it should be ordered alphabetically on the basis of Dept_Name. How can I do that?

Comment: Really? See ORDER BY.

Comment: Also, the title has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I'm sorry. The title pertains to my another question. However, I was not able to get the desired output as there is a condition on order by.

Answer (score 0):

See [SQL ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp). By default it sorts records in ascending order, unless specified otherwise (DESC).

```
select dept_name, count(emp_id)
from yourtable
group by dept_name
order by count(emp_id) desc, dept_name
```